# Javascript regular expression for email validation we should not allow duplicate words after @ in the email

Tags: javascript, regex

```
 function verifyEmail(component){
        var status = false;
        var emailAddress = component.value;
        if(emailAddress == ""){
            return true;
        }
        var emailRegEx = /^([A-Z0-9._%+-])+@([A-Z0-9.-])+\.([A-Z])+$/i;
             if (!(emailAddress.search(emailRegEx) == -1)) {
                 status = true;
             }
             return status;
    }
```

This regex accepting duplicate words after @ . Eg: leela.lokesh@in.csc.com.com
Here com word is coming 2 times. we should not allow duplicate words after '@'

Comment: Please modify the title or it is a duplicate of [Validate email address in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript?rq=1).

Comment: `leela.lokesh@in.csc.com.com` is a valid email address.

Comment: In the email address after @ duplicate words not allowed. I have given one emailRegEx it is not working. Can you provide any suggestions.If i give leela.suresh@in.csc.com.com it is taking.

Comment: after@ there should not be any duplicate words. Eg: Gopi.infy@in.infy.infy.com.com if we see this email address after @ there are two infy words and two com words . those duplicates we should not allow

Answer (score 0):

```
 var emailRegEx = /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/
```

Comment: it is not working it is allowing duplicate words.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this 
/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/

Comment: it is not working it is allowing duplicates

Comment: after@ there should not be any duplicate words. Eg: Gopi.infy@in.infy.infy.com.com if we see this email address after @ there are two infy  words and two com words . those duplicates we should not allow